# AcquireJobsRunnableImpl trows PSQLException: SSL error: readHandshakeRecord

Tags: alfresco

With a successfully migrated Alfresco (5.2 to) 7.0 repository, I get `PSQLException: SSL error: readHandshakeRecord` (see stracktrace below) every morning at 4:00, which then causes the repository to stop responding.

Could someone please help me decipher this stack trace? Why is this job running around 4am? I can't find a suitable quartz job. Does anyone know how to manually force this call to fix this problem? At first I thought it might be related to the contentStoreCleaner running at 4:00 am, but disabling this job doesn't change anything.

The only work around I found so far was to disable the activity workflow engine.

```
2021-08-08 04:35:39,396 ERROR [org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnableImpl] [Thread-46] exception during job acquisition: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: readHandshakeRecord
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: readHandshakeRecord
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnableImpl.run(AcquireJobsRunnableImpl.java:54)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: readHandshakeRecord
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:534)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:149)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1335)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
        ... 22 more
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:380)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
                ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:251)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedProducer.onProduceFinished(Finished.java:679)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedProducer.produce(Finished.java:658)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:1011)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:874)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: I had previously asked the same question in the Alfresco forum, but it was removed as SPAM. In the meantime, however, the question has been unmarked and can also be also found [there in the ACS forum](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/psqlexception-ssl-error-readhandshakerecord-for/m-p/308502/highlight/false#M25037). So sorry for the cross posting ...

Comment: I'd check your postgresql configuration, looks to me like that's the source of the disconnect / error

Comment: @Gagravarr what do you suggets to check on the postgres side? In the postgres log I don't see any issues and there are lots of connections free when the issue occours. The postgres db had been migrated from 9.6 to 13 but I use more or less the same parameters in postgresql.conf

Comment: it seems this exception just means the db run out of configured open_connections. Although we use more or less the same config for the upgraded system we now started to sort out possible root causes by deactivating jobs in Alfresco: activity workflow engine, activties feed ... I will also script some monitoring on the db connections.

Comment: IIRC you need to allow a few more connections on the postgresql side than Alfresco uses, so there is spare for admin/maintenance tasks. Check how many threads you allow in tomcat, and what size pool you have as a max in Alfresco - https://docs.alfresco.com/process-services/latest/config/database/

Comment: thanks @Gagravarr thats pretty clear. The odd thing is that I already increased the number of connections on both sides to 350 although there is only one (application) user connected at the time when the issue occurs. So it may be something like a internal batch, cron, ... maybe the db monitoring will shed some light on it

Comment: You may find you have more luck on https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postgresql with your query - DBAs and SysAdmins tend to hang out there more than here! (Same login works, all part of the StackExchange network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace was misleading - the jdbc connection problem was caused by memory filling up by the Alfresco trashcan cleaner module: [OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space due to no limit on getChildAssocs](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-trashcan-cleaner-module/issues/2).

We have ~ 4 million nodes in the trashcan and the module retrieves in every batch run *all* nodes again and again until the memory has been filled up ...